# stop all IP and domain requests and only my front-end domain can access to backend

Tags: api, nginx, backend

Quick question Can u please tell me how I can stop all IP and domain requests and only my front-end domain can access to backend. my front end has no IP address I'm using Cloudflare Workers so any suggestion to stop all connections and only one domain can access?

Thanks in advance
my domain config on NGINX

```
    server_name api.domain.com;
    root /var/www/api.domain.com;

location / {
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5005;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                           # Simple requests

    }


listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}server {

    enter code here

if ($host = api.domain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name api.domain.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```